# Text box where user enters name,can be first name or last name or both then record data is displayed on to screen.Stored procedure logic fails

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a text box where user enters name can be first name,last name or both.This all is entered in a single user input text box.Then the sql stored procedure should search for name(first,name,last name) can even be multiple records where the user can select a specific name from repetitive name in a popup or a simple table.
I am don't have much skills in sql server.I am having problems getting the logic right.

The code till now is as follows-

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[getfullnamereturnTest]
@NameSearch nvarchar(max)
AS

begin

   if exists (select * from testingtable where firstname='@NameSearch') 
begin
select distinct testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname,testingtable.country  from testingtable inner join
(
select testingtable.firstname,COUNT(*) as repitingnamesno
from testingtable
where testingtable.firstname ='@NameSearch'
group by testingtable.firstname
having count(testingtable.firstname)>1)
subq ON testingtable.firstname = subq.firstname
end
else if exists (select * from testingtable where lastname='@NameSearch')
begin
select distinct testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname,testingtable.country  from testingtable inner join
(
select testingtable.lastname,COUNT(*) as repitingnamesno
from testingtable
where testingtable.lastname ='@NameSearch'
group by testingtable.lastname
having count (testingtable.lastname)>1 )
subq ON testingtable.lastname = subq.lastname
end

else
begin
select distinct testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname,testingtable.country  from testingtable inner join
(
select testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname,COUNT(*) as repitingnamesno
from testingtable
where testingtable.firstname+testingtable.lastname ='@NameSearch'
group by testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname
having count (testingtable.firstname+testingtable.lastname)>1 ) 
subq ON testingtable.firstname = subq.firstname AND testingtable.lastname = subq.lastname
end
end
go
```

Searching for last name with 'reddy'

```
exec getfullnamereturnTest @NameSearch='reddy'
```

The stored procedure returns empty table.Even when it consists of multiple records on name.But when i just executed the query without input parameter as below and it works fine.

```
 if exists (select * from testingtable where firstname='reddy') 
begin
select distinct testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname,testingtable.country  from testingtable inner join
(
select testingtable.firstname,COUNT(*) as repitingnamesno
from testingtable
where testingtable.firstname ='reddy'
group by testingtable.firstname
having count(testingtable.firstname)>1)
subq ON testingtable.firstname = subq.firstname
end
else if exists (select * from testingtable where lastname='reddy')
begin
select distinct testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname,testingtable.country  from testingtable inner join
(
select testingtable.lastname,COUNT(*) as repitingnamesno
from testingtable
where testingtable.lastname ='reddy'
group by testingtable.lastname
having count (testingtable.lastname)>1 )
subq ON testingtable.lastname = subq.lastname
end

else
begin
select distinct testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname,testingtable.country  from testingtable inner join
(
select testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname,COUNT(*) as repitingnamesno
from testingtable
where testingtable.firstname+testingtable.lastname ='reddy'
group by testingtable.firstname,testingtable.lastname
having count (testingtable.firstname+testingtable.lastname)>1 ) 
subq ON testingtable.firstname = subq.firstname AND testingtable.lastname = subq.lastname
end
```

It returns output as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np4gw.png)

The table consists of the following values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzjZG.png)

Table data-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testingtable](  [firstname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    [lastname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,     [country] [nvarchar](max) NULL ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO testingtable (firstname, lastname, country) 
   VALUES ('sruthi','Yarramreddy' , 'IND'), 
          ('sruthi','chiluka' , 'US'),
          ('amulya', 'reddy', 'BZ'), 
          ('amulya', 'Choudary', 'Uk'),
          ('avasya', 'Koneru', 'US'),
           ('avasya', 'Koneru', 'AUS'),
          ('amulya', 'reddy', 'BZ'),
           ('avasya', 'Koneru', 'US'),
           ('sruthi','K' , 'AUS'),
           ('sruthi','yaramreddy' , 'AUS');
```

Comment: The performance of this is going to be horrible. You have a couple things going on here. First is this is a multiple execution path type of procedure. You can read more about this here. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/ The second issue is that this is also likely a "catch all" type of query. This also has some challenges from a performance perspective. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Before anybody can really help much here we need some more information. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: yes , this is a multiple execution path as i have to search with firstname,lastname and full name.It has to "catch all".

Comment: If you don't really need the count this could easily be accomplished in a single query.

Comment: Is it possible to even get multiple records with same name without count?

Comment: Of course it is. Did you try?

Comment: Sorry i haven't..can you please help me with this.How does the code look like..

Comment: Don't use a group by if you want multiple rows. This is really the absolute basics of querying data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is really what you are after but here is my best guess.

```
select firstname, lastname, country
from testingtable
where firstname = @NameSearch
    OR lastname = @NameSearch
```

Also, Country should NOT be varchar(max). It should a char(2) or char(3) depending on which standard you are using. You seem to be mixing 2 and 3 character country codes. It should also be a foreign key to a Country table.

For querying basics the Stairways series on SQL Server Central is awesome. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/75773/

Comment: Hi, then how do i search both first name and last name together.I have only single text box for all firstname.lastname and full name to be entered.And i want single data record to be auto populated on to text boxes like "Textbox1- [Name]" - firstname/last name/full name "Textbox2- [country]"- country name.But if it has 2 records with same name from textbox 1 then a popup appears to select one from multiple

Comment: You would add another condition to the where clause. OR firstname + ' ' + lastname = @NameSearch. You really need to put some effort into this. We are not a code writing service.